# When is a device operating under Part 97 and when is it under Part 15?

Tags: united-states, radio, amateur-radio

I have a packet digital radio transceiver that is completely compliant with both [Part 15](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-A/part-15) (unlicensed radio devices) and [Part 97](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97) (amateur radio) regulations. I can send information in a way that complies with either or both sets of rules.

For any individual transmission, what determines which regulations apply? It operates on a frequency that is both ISM and amateur. Can I say "this transmission was under Part 15, so it's okay that it was encrypted, but this one that was sent a few milliseconds later was under Part 97, so it's okay that it was relayed to someone else by an automatic amateur radio digital message forwarder station that I operate"?

Would including my amateur call sign in a packet prove I intended it to be an amateur transmission? If I send an encrypted packet that would otherwise be a legal Part 15 transmission, but add my amateur call sign, does this make it an illegal Part 97 transmission?

Comment: Do you have an amateur radio operator's license?

Comment: @Mark yes, I do.

Comment: Are the regulations mutually exclusive, whether explicitly or implicitly?  From the question it sounds like each regulation permits something.  That doesn't imply that doing one thing prohibits the other simply because it is the subject of a different regulation.  With restrictive laws, acts must comply with all of them.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained so can you provide a link and quote relevant extract from the regulations, please.

Comment: @phoog I **think** radio licenses "stack permissively": you can do these things, also you can do these things, also you can do these things. (IANAL;TINLA)

Comment: @Rick I can link to them, but Part 15 and Part 97 are quite long, and I'm not sure which sections apply.

Comment: @phoog normally, radio devices are only used under one set of regulations, so it's fairly clear. There's no doubt that my garage door remote is Part 15, or that single-sideband transmission is Part 97, even if they are on the same frequency. An amateur station is not permitted to communicate with an unlicensed device. I'm just not sure when my device is an amateur station and when it's unlicensed.

Comment: @user253751 ^^^

Comment: @Someone what's the actual rule? does it say "An amateur station is not permitted to communicate with an unlicensed device" or is it different from that? I imagine that it says an amateur station may only communicate with other amateur stations?